# JOOQ custom code generator with maven mojos

Tags: java, maven, jooq, maven-mojo

I have a custom code generator extending `JavaGenerator` and it would be very useful if the user using this generator could specify additional information like a list of column names to which the custom generator applies to.
My first though would be to add configuration options to the dependency with [mojos](https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html).
However this does not seem to work properly because during the build cycle two separate instance are created, once from maven and once from JOOQ.

This is my custom generator:

```java
@Mojo(name="generation")
public class CustomGenerator extends JavaGenerator implements org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo, ContextEnabled {

    @Parameter(property="tableNames")
    private List tableNames;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomGenerator.class);
    @Override
    protected void generateSchema(SchemaDefinition schema) {
        //custom code generation based on the variable "tableNames"
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
        //called when maven instantiates this class
    }

    //bunch of empty methods I do not care about but have to be there because
    //I cannot let this class also extend from AbstractMojo

    @Override
    public void setPluginContext(Map map) {

    }

    @Override
    public Map getPluginContext() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setLog(Log log) {

    }

    @Override
    public Log getLog() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And this is my pom of the project where I use the generator and want to supply additional information:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
    <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
    <version>3.15.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <generator>
            <name>org.example.CustomGenerator</name>
        </generator>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>customgenerator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <tableNames>
            <tableName>test_table</tableName>
        </tableNames>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generation</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>customgenerator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If there are any other methods to supply custom information to the generator, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using `database` properties

Maybe, much simpler, use the `properties` available in `database` as follows:

```xml
<configuration>
  <generator>
    <database>
      <properties>
        <property>
          <key>some_key</key>
          <value>some_value</value>
        </property>
      </properties>
    </database>
  </generator>
</configuration>
```

There's no specification what you place as `key/value` in those properties. They've been added for purposes like yours, e.g. to add custom configuration to advanced `<database>` implementations like:

- [`DDLDatabase`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-ddl/)
- [`XMLDatabase`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-xml/)
- [`LiquibaseDatabase`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-liquibase/)
- [`JPADatabase`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-jpa/)

See also those sections to see how the properties are used by those databases.

Your custom `JavaGenerator` logic can then access the properties via:

```java
Properties properties = definition.getDatabase().getProperties();
```

Where `definition` is any object that is being generated, e.g. `SchemaDefinition` in your code.

#### Simplest solution

Of course, setting system properties is always a pragmatic option.